# Can a cdf yield negative proability?

Tags: probability, statistics

I have the pdf $f( x) =\begin{cases}
2x^{-3} & \text{if } x\geqslant 1\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$

Integrating, I get that the cdf is

$F_{X} =-\frac{1}{x^{2}}\text{ for } x\geqslant 1$

However, this doesn't make any sense to me because the probabilities are negative. Where am I wrong? Thanks

Comment: That's not correct. It should be $ F_X(x) = \displaystyle \int_1^x 2x^{-3} ~ dx$

Comment: Plus a constant.  The constant is $1$.

Comment: @mathlover I’m sure you know this, but one shouldn’t use the same letter $x$ for a limit of integration and for the dummy variable in the integral.

Answer (score 1):

$F_X(x)=\int_1^{x}2t^{-3}dt=-t^{-2}|_1^{x}=1-x^{-2}$ for $1 \leq x <\infty$.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't get the limits of integration right. Thank you!